# Spy++ and windows closed when they lose focus

Tags: windows, spy++

I would like to know if there is a way with Spy++ to get the properties of a window that is automatically closed when it loses the focus (which is what happens when I switch to Spy++). Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Please try - Active Accessibility Object Inspector (32-bit UNICODE Release) , it may useful.

if not then please explain your question briefly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Messaging service in order to get the properties of the window. For example, if you want to know WID for menu item, you need to identify the target window by using Window Finder Tool from Window Tab of Message Option dialogue and then clear all messages from Message tab. You only need to choose VM_COMMAND. After that when you click any menu item from target window menu list, associated ID will be shown in Spy++ main window.

Hopefully the answer will be useful for you.

Thanks.

Comment: The window can't appear in Spy++'s target window list until you choose Refresh in Spy++ while the window exists.  But this is impossible if merely switching to Spy++ to start a refresh causes the window to close.

Answer (score 1):

When the SPY mode is active in QTP, hold the CONTROL-button down for mouse clicks to re-establish the correct context for the AUT (application under test).  Basically these control-mouseclicks will be ignored by the spy and pass through to the application.

Good question!

Ziggy